# What is "bundle" in Beam Flink Runner

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam

I am running a Flink pipeline on Beam with the Flink Runner. Beam provides some configurations for Flink such as "maxBundleSize" and "maxBundleTimeMills". (see [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/flink/))

My question is: what is a "bundle"?

I believe the answer lies within [this](https://github.com/axbaretto/beam/blob/master/runners/flink/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/runners/flink/translation/wrappers/streaming/DoFnOperator.java) source-code but I couldn't explain the meaning of "bundle".

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's part of Beam execution model, not limited to Flink Runner, [see here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/execution-model/#bundling-and-persistence). Bundle is a collection of elements that the runner decides to pass around together to optimize persistence and transfer, for example so that instead of writing or sending over a lot of elements one-by-one, you instead bundle them up into a collection and send the collection over. It is likely going to be more efficient this way. How large the bundle can be is runner specific and, like in case of Flink Runner, you can configure this logic to some degree. You should not have to deal with bundles unless you have some really specific need to (e.g. optimize the performance, deal with resource allocation, etc), their existence is largely transparent to the pipeline authors, it's part of how the pipeline is executed, not a major top-level primitive that you have to deal with to describe the business logic.

Comment: Thank you for the nice information. If I understood correctly, Beam is not processing tuples record-by-record. Does this mean that Beam is using Flink's batch processing all the time?